# Ngx Leaflet GeoJson with layers - how to only render a part (square) of the map for performance optimisation?

Tags: angular, leaflet, gis, geojson, ngx-leaflet

For performance purposes I am looking for help with only displaying a part of the map with toggleable layers.

Since my GeoJSON file contains too many features, the map gets really laggy, so I want to only render a part (square) of the map and when the user presses up/down/left/right, the map moves by it's entire size to the next square.

I started looking into geojsonvt for vector tiles, but the result is in mapbox format which can't be shown in leaflet. I am also not sure if vector tiles keep the original GeoJSON shapes, because i need to be able to snap on them for distance measuring and for getting the coordinates of them. The shapes are lines, polylines, polygons,..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're looking for Leaflet.VectorGrid.Slicer.

Comment: Thank you. I see you're also the author. I will try to add a type definition file for it later, if I'll be able to figure it out.